# Load object from table with id as foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

i have define users with UserRole type Role as foreing key of another table. Entiti framework auto transformed name UserRole to UserRoleId with type integer (Id). Its ok. But i have UserRoleId = 2 in table [User table preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LAij.png)
and when i trying get user by Id:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
```

so parameter UserRole is null [user preview from debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQNNG.png).

Application user:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int PriorityLevel { get; set; }
    public Role UserRole { get; set; }
    public string ForName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string WorkPlace { get; set; }
    public string Notice { get; set; }
}
```

Must i use some entity framework command for load UserRole as type Role? Or can i get UserRoleId from table?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged your question with Entity Framework, but just in case, I'll cover Entity Framework Core, as well, since they diverge slightly on this.

Entity Framework supports lazy-loading, but importantly, the property must be `virtual` to enable that, i.e.:

```
public virtual Role UserRole { get; set; }
```

EF adds the logic necessary to do lazy-load the property by deriving a dynamic "proxy" class from your entity and overriding the property. Since non-`virtual` properties cannot be overridden, this logic is not added to properties without `virtual`.  Without `virtual`, navigation properties *will not* be loaded automatically, and will remain `null`, whether there's associations in the database or not.

Entity Framework Core does not support lazy-loading *at all*, so adding `virtual` will not help you.

In either case, you should really be eager-loading, instead. This is done by adding `Include` to your query. However, you have two problems there:

1. `UserManager<TUser>` doesn't support including related entities. You would need to use the `DbSet`, i.e. `context.Users`.
2. You cannot use `Include` with `Find` (or any of the `Find`-related methods), as it has logic that is incompatible with doing joins. Namely, `Find` attempts to pull the entity from the context cache without doing a query at all, if possible, and as such, cannot guarantee that navigation properties can be included. As a result, you will have to switch to something like `SingleOrDefault`.

```
var user = await context.Users.Include(x => x.UserRole).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

With that, `UserRole` should now actually have a value.

Alternatively, you should be able to explicitly-load `UserRole`:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
context.Entry(user).Reference(s => s.UserRole).Load();
```

This methodology is the same in both Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core. However it was only introduced into EF Core in 1.1, so be cognizant of the version you're running. The one downside here is that this will result in (potentially) two queries. Again, since the `Find` methods attempt to retrieve from the context cache, it's *possible* you'll avoid a query there, but the entity is not in the cache, it will take two queries: one for the user and one for the related role. However, that would have been the case as well with lazy-loading. Only eagerly-loading allows the queries to be combined using `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the roles of the user using this method.

```
_userManager.GetRolesAsync(id);
```

Comment: I think its miscrosoft original implementation for Role in table but UserRole is my implementation.

Comment: So I would suggest to stick to M$ implementation to not reinvent the wheel